# Django Gunicorn Nginx summernote image upload error

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, summernote

**My problem**

make blog by summernote

and  use Nignx, Gunicorn

but upload image use summernote

error code apear this

```
nginx_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2022:11:45:48 +0000] "POST /summernote/upload_attachment/ HTTP/1.1" 200 181 "http://127.0.0.1/summernote/editor/id_content/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2022:11:45:48 +0000] "GET /media/django-summernote/2022-08-14/76f471c6-b864-478a-a06b-4062b11c6ed8.png HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://127.0.0.1/summernote/editor/id_content/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1  | 2022/08/14 11:45:48 [error] 22#22: *1 open() "/usr/src/app/_media/django-summernote/2022-08-14/76f471c6-b864-478a-a06b-4062b11c6ed8.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/django-summernote/2022-08-14/76f471c6-b864-478a-a06b-4062b11c6ed8.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/summernote/editor/id_content/"
```

**I want know meaning of this error message**

Answer (score 0):

```bash
nginx_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2022:11:45:48 +0000] "GET /media/django-summernote/2022-08-14/76f471c6-b864-478a-a06b-4062b11c6ed8.png HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://127.0.0.1/summernote/editor/id_content/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

> GET /media/django-summernote/2022-08-14/76f471c6-b864-478a-a06b-4062b11c6ed8.png HTTP/1.1" 404

You have a [404 http error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) on the route you try to GET

```bash
nginx_1  | 2022/08/14 11:45:48 [error] 22#22: *1 open() "/usr/src/app/_media/django-summernote/2022-08-14/76f471c6-b864-478a-a06b-4062b11c6ed8.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/django-summernote/2022-08-14/76f471c6-b864-478a-a06b-4062b11c6ed8.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/summernote/editor/id_content/"
```

> open() "/usr/src/app/_media/django-summernote/2022-08-14/76f471c6-b864-478a-a06b-4062b11c6ed8.png" failed (2: No such file or directory)

As the above error explicitly say you try to open a file that doesn't exist.
This is the result of the HTTP response 404, you try to retrieve a file that doesn't exist (and maybe store it) and then open it.